# trick double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Edwards and Penney. Calculus Early Transcendentals. 7th edition, page 1018. $R$ is the unit disk in the $xy$-plane. Evaluate
$$
\iint_R\left(5-x^2\sin{}x+y^3\cos{}y\right)\,dA
$$
It's a "trick integral" in the sense that it's easier to think about the volume of the solid with the unit disk at the base instead of actually integrating (using iterated integrals); but I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: After breaking it into three double integrals:
$$\iint_R 5\, dA - \iint_R x^2\sin x\, dA + \iint_R y^3\cos y\, dA,$$
think which of these three you could realistically compute (or interpret as a volume). For the other(s), is there any symmetry within $R$ that allows you to know the value of the integral?

If you haven't used symmetry arguments before, consider a basic integral $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 x^3\, dx$.

Comment: Thank you! The answer is then just $5\pi$, since the other two integrals are zero.